# Cannot find or open PDB File error when running the program even though it builds successfully

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11, visual-c++

I have a project in visual c++ where I am referring some external DLL.
I have already included the lib directory in linker section and mention it in the input section of the linker and also included the same in c/c++ General Additional Include Directories section.

Thus the project compiles successfully but whenever I try to run it; it fails with an error "Application was unable to start correctly" but if I see the output section it seems everything is loaded correctly but against that particular Dll it says that "Cannot find or open the PDB file".

How to fix this error so that I can run my program. It is an MFC program running in Visual Studio 2010.
when I run the program through the Dependency Walker, most of the API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP, FILE, and EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION USERMGR -l1-1-0.dll many similar to this are unavailable. I even tried to repair the visual studio it didn't work. Is there any idea how to go about it

Comment: it says the  error 00000x7b

Comment: when I run the program through the Dependency Walker, most of the API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP, FILE, and EXT-MS-WIN-SESSION USERMGR -l1-1-0.dll many similar to this are unavailable.
I even tried to repair the visual studio it didn't work. Is there any idea how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

`0x0000007b` sounds familiar to me.

Most likely that is due to 32/64 bit library mixture you are linking with.

Either you are building for x64 and linking with a win32 external library or vice versa.

In your Visual Studio project settings separately configure platform architectures you are compiling for and then you can choose the profile which you are actually compiling for.